# Get updated image from Drawing cache

Tags: android, bitmap

I am able to get the bitmap of my screen using the following code :-

```
mainView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap b = mainView.getDrawingCache();
```

But before getting the bitmap from drawing cache I want to disable a button on my screen, so that it should not appear in the image.

I tried doing following before getting the bitmap :-

```
btnSave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

and also tried

```
btnSave.setAlpha(0);
```

But still the button appears in the image.

Has anyone managed to do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this view Gone

```
btnSave.setVisibility(View.Gone);
```

instead of

```
btnSave.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the button and get the drawing cache. Then add again button to its parent view.